# Какого рода слово «шлепень»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, этимология, существительные, род

Не каждый этот шлепень сможет проглотить.

Comment: Ну если "этот", то мужского, нет?!

Comment: Что такое шлепень? Лепешка?

Answer (score 0):

Если «шлепень» сленговое образование от «slap» – пощечина, то возможно использование слова (в зависимости от желания и фантазии произносящего) и в женском, и в мужском роде.

"Пощечина" преобразована в "шлепень" посредством слова «шлепок», переиначенного окончанием «ень» (для созвучия со словами м. р.: день, пень, слепень).

https://studfiles.net/preview/3351724/page:8/

В вопросе приведен пример употребления слова только в м. р. Почему так, понять сложно.

Answer (score -1):

Общий род.

Шлёпень - о неуклюжем, неповоротливом человеке.

Другие примеры общего рода: плакса, тихоня.

Comment: Нытик - не общего рода. ))) Как, впрочем, и шелепень.

Comment: Убрал со списка. Хотя в интернет-справочниках фиксируется с общим родом. Разве девочку нытиком нельзя назвать?

Comment: Вы же не дали никаких ссылок на "справочник". Тогда бы все претензии - к нему. Но вообще дико такое читать. Может, конечно, что-тот поменялось в "доме Облонских"... Но я с таким не сталкивался. Общий род - это только слова на а/я. Остальное - в тексте моего ответа.

Comment: Брал [отсюда](https://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/6-klass/imia-sushchestvitelnoe-10556/imia-sushchestvitelnoe-kak-chast-rechi-10557/re-3c038194-6fbd-425b-ab64-1354531274f8). Но полно и [других](https://shkolnaiapora.ru/russkij-yazyk/rod-imyon-sushhestvitelnyx.html).

Comment: @behemothus Чем вы подтвердите, что у общего рода только окончания а/я?

Comment: https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200701512

Comment: http://www.russisch-fuer-kinder.de/de_start/schule/texte.php?auswahl=is_rod_common

Comment: Ну так понятно, что большинство слов имеют такие окончания. Но там не сказано, что исключительно.

Answer (score -1):

Судя по словарной фиксации - мужского: "вятский шелепень". 
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/49627/%D0%92%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

Об общем роде.
Идея о том, что слово может быть "общего рода" не имеет почвы для существования. К общему роду относятся преимущественно слова на "-а/я", обозначающие лиц по профессии или в качестве некик характеристик-прозвищ.

Однако то, что некое прозвище (характеристика, эпитет) в принципе применимо к лицам любого пола, не делает грамматический род общим (нормативность конструкции типа "наша врач" - не затрагивает грамматического рода слова "врач" как такового). Но в нашем случае даже таких признаков не просматривается. "Вятская шлепень" не фиксируется.

Смысл фразы "не каждый может проглотить" остается туманным. Разве шлепеней глотают?!

Comment: Сам Розенталь утверждал, что понятие рода самое сложное (спорное) в русском языке.

Comment: @oleedd  Розенталь давно умер, а вы все флудите.

Comment: Какое неуважение!.. Тогда и справочниками его не пользуйтесь, раз так. Дизлайк вам. Его точка зрения явно достойна упоминания.